# If there exist numbers M and m such that m < f(a) < M, prove that there exist positive numbers ε and δ such that m + ε < f(x) < M - ε

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Suppose that a is a real number and I is an open interval which contains a. If f: I → R satisfies f(x) → f(a), as x → a and if there exist numbers M and m such that m < f(a) < M, prove that there exist positive numbers ε and δ such that m + ε < f(x) < M - ε for all x's which satisfy |x-a| < δ.

proof: By definition if |x-a| < δ implies |f(x) - f(a)| < ε. Then  -ε < f(x) - f(a)| < ε implies  -ε + f(a) < f(x) < ε + f(a).
Since there exist numbers M and m such that m < f(a) < M. Then -ε + f(a) < f(x) < ε + f(a) implies -ε + m < f(x) < ε + M .

Can someone please help me? I think it is almost done.
Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\epsilon=\min\left\{\frac{f(a)-m}{2},\frac{M-f(a)}{2}\right\}$.

Comment: I don't understand why choose epsilon like that.